# Typesetting complete document within \end{...}

Tags: macros

**Task to solve:** The user provides the values of fields/variables (where the values may be arbitrary junks of LaTeX code), and in the end the document is typeset without intervention of the user. My idea is to have something like

```
\documentclass{myclass}
\begin{form}
   ... Specification of values in any order
\end{form}
```

LaTeX should remain in preamble mode until `\end{form}` to guarantee that no user input generates output (without errors). `\end{form}` then loads some template that uses the values from the user together with the usual elements of (La)TeX.

Code illustrating this approach:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\A[1]{\gdef\useA{#1}}
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{B}{\expandafter\gdef\expandafter\useB\expandafter{\BODY}}
\newenvironment{form}%
  {}%
  {\document
   A: \useA

   B: \useB
   \enddocument
  }
\begin{form}
  \A{aaa}
  \begin{B}
    bbb
  \end{B}
\end{form}
```

This code kind of works, but with at least one problem: `\document` starts with `\endgroup` to counter-act a `\begingroup` in the definition of `\begin` (which is not present). This has the not-so-nice effect that local definitions before `\document` are forgotten, everything has to be defined globally. It is unclear to me whether this is the only problem or whether there are more pitfalls ahead.

Using `\begin{document}` or `\begingroup\document` instead of `\document` results in the error that `\begin{form}` is ended by `\end{document}`, so this doesn't seem to be the right way either.

I may start picking only relevant parts of `\document` and `\enddocument`, omitting the `\begin`-`\end` stuff. This raises the ...

**Question:** What is the least hackerish/least intrusive/minimal way of starting and finishing the actual typesetting of a LaTeX document?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could execute the `document` environment just after the end of the `form` environment using an extra command and `\aftergroup`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\A[1]{\gdef\useA{#1}}
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{B}{\expandafter\gdef\expandafter\useB\expandafter{\BODY}}

\newenvironment{form}{}{%
  \aftergroup\setdocument
}

\newcommand*{\setdocument}{%
  \begin{document}
   A: \useA

   B: \useB
  \end{document}
}

\begin{form}
  \A{aaa}
  \begin{B}
    bbb
  \end{B}
\end{form}
```

Comment: Thanks, great, `\aftergroup` was the missing piece!